# PHP - MySQLi Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$name = $_GET['user'];
if(isset($_GET['user']) && strlen($_GET['user'])>0) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        if($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
            header("Location: home?errormsg=notfound");
            exit();
        }
    }
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

So, the above code checks if $_GET['name'] exists in the database, and if it doesn't, to redirect to home?errormsg=notfound but it redirects the usernames which exists in the database to the link 'home?errormsg=notfound' as well. Can you suggest a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not check for the existence with a COUNT statement? `SELECT COUNT(*) AS uncnt FROM users WHERE username=?`. It's just as fast as selecting the username itself (which you then basically throw away) and semantically more explicit what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `$stmt->store_result()` before `$stmt->num_rows`.

And your `$stmt->fetch()` is not necessary, because you don't use the selected data.

If you call `store_result()` after `num_rows` it won't work.

Part of comment from [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php):

> If you do not use mysqli_stmt_store_result( ), and immediatley call
>   this function after executing a prepared statement, this function will
>   usually return 0 as it has no way to know how many rows are in the
>   result set as the result set is not saved in memory yet.

**So your code should look like this:**

```
$name = $_GET['user'];
if(isset($_GET['user']) && strlen($_GET['user'])>0) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
        header("Location: home?errormsg=notfound");
        exit();
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but maybe it helps.

You are calling  `$stmt->store_result();` after `$stmt->num_rows`
Please try moving `$stmt->store_result();` before `$stmt->num_rows`

Example. you can see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)